# How can we create a folder of app in device storage in Android?

Tags: android

I'm using code in comment to save a file in directory folder. This code is working properly with mobile phone having sd card.

But if I use it with mobile phone not having sd card it is giving IO exception.
How can I create a folder like whatsapp has in device storage root to save images etc but I want a folder of application name to save .csv files in my device storage root.

Comment: The term "device storage" is not used in Android app development. There is [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), and [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). There is no "Environment.getstoragedirectory()" in the Android SDK, and it is unclear what you are referring to when you use the phrase "device storage".

Comment: please check your question while posting here and the answer which already available here

Comment: i want to have a folder like whatsapp have in device storage to store images bt i have  to store .csv files in that folder

Comment: Hi Sagar. I notice you are using txtspk words like `plz` and `bt`. If the words `please` and `but` are too much trouble for you to type, then Stack Overflow may not be for you. We _need_ to see effort in questions here, and even after my edits above, this will close, as it does not show what code and configuration you have.

Comment: I notice now that you have put a snippet of code in a comment. This should be in the question. Please edit it into the question, and delete the comment. A block formatting tool is available.

Comment: sorry sir i m using this first time . i will mind it next time

Answer (score 1):

**First make sure you have added Storage Permissions inside Manifest**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If you want to create folder inside `ExternalDirectory`

```
 File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/foldername");
 if(!f.exists()) f.mkdir();
```

If you want to create file inside internal storage

```
File mydir = context.getDir("mydir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal directory;
File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, "myfile");
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir);
```

Comment: i wnt to have a folder like whatsapp have in device storage to store my files .

Comment: Then you should use external storage method

Comment: how can u plz tell me the code to have a  folder like whatsapp if my phone is not having sd card

Comment: File export=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
Environment. DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
 File f= new File(export,"xyz.csv");
f.createNewFile();

Comment: i hve used this code when i m using with phone having sd card it is working unless it gives io exception

Comment: the external directory one

Comment: i tried it is only working with phones having sd card else it fails

Answer (score 0):

You can create directory in internal storage and external storage as Follows.

```
//check whether Sdcard present or not
Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);

if(isSDPresent)
{
  // yes SD-card is present
String directory = "/your Directory name or app name ";
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + directory;

    File dir = new File(path);
    if(!dir.exists())           //check if not created then create the firectory
                    dir.mkdirs();

//add your files in directory as follows 
 File file = new File(dir, filename);

}
else
{
 // create folder in internal memory
File mydir = context.getDir(directory, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal directry
   if(!mydir.exists())           //check if not created then create the firectory
         mydir.mkdirs();
    //add your files in directory as follows 

        File file = new File(mydir, filename);
```

I hope it will work for you

Comment: i hhave done this only and if i m using my app on phone having sd crd it works properly and if a phone doesnt have sd card it gives error io expection .

Comment: i edited the post @Sagar_Salal check it now. if its work for you please upvote

Comment: i hve updated my question please have a look over it

Comment: @Sagar_Salal i edited my answer please check it. I will work in both case if you have sdcard then it create folder there if sd card is not available then it will create folder in your internal storage.

Comment: yes it is created  and showing path storage/emulated/0/directoryname/filename .. bt it is not showing in my mobile phone

Comment: means my directory is not visible in my file explorer

Comment: now i edit answer @Sagar_Salal and its working fine at my phone. I hope it will work for you

Comment: it is only working bt not creating the directory in my storage of the directory name